# Let $P$ be prime and contain $IJ$, the product ideal. Then $I \subset P$ or $J \subset P$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-explanation

So I already witness the solution. It is this: Assume $I \not\subset P$, then there is $i \not\in P$. Then the product $ij \in IJ \subset P$, but since $P$ is prime, $i \in P$ or $j \in P$, so $J \subset P$.

here is what I don't get. Doesn't this only show a finite truncation belongs to $P$? Don't we have to show that for any finite sum $i_1j_1 + \dots + i_nj_n \in P$, $i_n \in P$ for every $n$ (assuming $|J| = |I| = n$ for ease of argument)

Comment: What does $|I|$ mean? At any rate, while it is true that such finite sums belong to $IJ$, you don't need to use that fact - it surely is true that $ij\in IJ$ and this is enough.

Comment: What is your definition of prime ideal? This definition is the one that works in non-commutative settings.

Comment: @Math_QED $ab \in P$, then $a \in P$ or $b \in P.$

Comment: @Hawk If you are working with commutative rings, always be sure to use the [commutative-algebra] tag and/or mention commutativity in the post.

Answer (score 5):

The proof as written is phrased a little awkwardly and missing important details.  Here is a correct proof (with everything spelled out):

Suppose $IJ \subset P$ and $I \subsetneq P$. We wish to show that for all $j \in J$, we have $j \in P$. Fix $j \in J$ $i \in I \setminus P$ and note that $ij \in IJ$. Since $IJ \subset P$, we have that $ij \in P$ but $P$ is prime, so we must have that either $i \in P$ or $j \in P$. Since $i \notin P$ (remember, $i \in I \setminus P$), we conclude that $j \in J$. This shows that $J \subset P$.

As far as the finite sums go, they belong to $IJ$ and thus to $P$ by assumption.

Answer (score 4):

Well, suppose $I\not\subset P$. Then there is $i\in I$ such that $i\not\in P$. For EACH $j\in J$, $ij\in IJ\subseteq P$ by hypothesis. But $P$ is prime and so $j\in P$. Hence $J\subseteq P$.